# Auto pull git repositories for opengrok indexing

Tags: git, gitlab, opengrok

I've installed opengrok from a docker image on an Ubuntu server.
Inside /var/opengrok/src, I cloned the desired repositories.
I'd like to auto pull and auto index changes periodically.
I'm not at ease with cron, is there a way to tell opengrok to pull before indexing?

- /var/opengrok/

  - docker-compose.yml
  - etc/
  - data/
  - src/

    - repo1-master/   <- need to `git pull`
    - repo1-dev/      <- need to `git pull`
    - repo2-master/   <- need to `git pull`
    - repo2-dev/      <- need to `git pull`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally wrote a cron task to run this script:

**pull-repos.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
repo_dirs=`ls -d /home/myuser/docker/opengrok/src/*`

for dir in $repo_dirs
do
        echo "Git pulling in $dir"
        cd $dir && git pull && cd ..
done
```

Here is the cron line:

```
*/15 9-18 * * mon,tue,wed,thu,fri /home/myuser/docker/opengrok/pull-repos.sh
```